# Spectrum of double infinite shift using isometry to Fourier series

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to find the spectrum of the operator $T: l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \to l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ given by right shift but I am having some difficulties.

I can show that $l^2$ is isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ via $\phi: (\alpha_n) \to \sum \alpha_n z^n$ where $z = e^{it}$ and then under this map $T$ acts on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ by $f \to zf$.

I'm now trying to find the spectrum of this multiplication operator. It's easy to show that the point spectrum is empty. The operator is unitary and so the spectrum must lie in the unit circle and it's normal so the spectrum must be entirely approximate point.

I'm struggling to find the approximate point spectrum. In particular I'm not quite sure how we should write the norm on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. Usually we should look for functions $f_n$ with $||(\lambda I - T)f_n|| = \int_{0} ^{2 \pi} |\lambda - e^{it}||f(t)| \to 0$ but this seems no easier than finding the approximate point spectrum of $T$ as an operator on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ so I feel like I'm missing something - perhaps there is a better way to write the norm in terms of $z = e^it$ to take advantage of being able to write the operator as multiplication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use $L^{2}(\mathbb{T})$ or $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ is a matter of preference. I prefer the classical Fourier setting
$$
                 U : L^{2}[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})
$$
defined by
$$
                 Uf = \left\{ \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)\frac{e^{-int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt\right\}_{n=--\infty}^{\infty}
$$
The inverse of $U$ is
$$
                   U \{ c_{n} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n} \frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
$U$ is unitary because $\{ \frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ with inner product $(f,g)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$. If $S$ is the right shift on $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, then
$$
                      U^{-1}SUf = e^{it}f(t).
$$
Every $|\lambda|$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $Mf = e^{it}f$. For example, if $0 < \theta < 2\pi$, consider $\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\theta+\delta]}$. Then
\begin{align}
       \|(M-e^{i\theta}I)\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\theta+\delta]}\|^{2} & =       \int_{0}^{2\pi}|(M-e^{i\theta}I)\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\delta+\delta]}|^{2}dt \\
   & = \int_{\theta-\delta}^{\theta+\delta}|e^{it}-e^{i\theta}|^{2}dt \\
   & \le |e^{i\delta}-1|^{2}\|\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\theta+\delta]}\|^{2} \\
   & = [(1-\cos\delta)^{2}+\sin^{2}\delta]\|\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\theta+\delta]}\|^{2} \\
   & = 2(1-\cos\delta)\|\chi_{[\theta-\delta,\theta+\delta]}\|^{2}
\end{align}
The conclusion is that every $\lambda$ for which $|\lambda|=1$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $M$ and, hence, also of the shift $S$.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of on the right track. Let's write things out a little bit more explicitly. Consider

$$(\lambda I-T)f = \lambda f - Tf = \lambda f - zf = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda \alpha_n z^n - \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^{n+1}.$$

Reindexing, the second sum becomes $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha_{n-1} z^n$ so the above becomes

$$(\lambda I - T)f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (\lambda\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1})z^n.$$

As you note, we want to find $f_i$ such that $\|(\lambda I - T)f_i\|\to 0$. To do this, it's best to sort of reduce yourself to the case of $\ell^2(\Bbb N_0)$ since there the right shift operator is easily understood. This is accomplished by considering those $f_i$ such that $f_i = (\ldots, 0, a_{i0},a_{i1},\ldots)$, where $a_{i0}$ occurs at the zeroth spot and eventually the $a_{ij}$ are zero.

To make things as simple on ourselves as possible, we'd like to set up a recursion of sorts with the $\alpha_i$ (so that there is cancellation to make the computation easy) and so we'd naively pick $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{\lambda}\alpha_{n-1}$. This gives the following candidate elements:

$$f_i = (\ldots, 0, 1, \lambda^{-1},\lambda^{-2},\ldots,\lambda^{1-n},0,\ldots).$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand the reasoning but in that case what is the point of setting up the isometry to $L^2 (\mathbb{T})$ it seems kind of irrelevant because we could just find the approximate point spectrum of the operator in $l^2$?

Comment: You could easily translate this into the language of $L^2(\Bbb T)$ with no problem (use the Fourier series of the $f_i$ above). The thing is that these Hilbert spaces are all the same, they're just different representations of the same thing. I think the proofs would end up being the same - logically - no matter which realization you used.

Comment: Does it not seem like you might get something extra by being able to write the operator as multiplication $f \to zf(z)$? It seems simpler than a shift operator then?

Comment: Well the thing is that those operators are in fact equivalent. This equivalence is solidified by the spectral theorem.